# what is this requirement telling me not to do?

Tags: c++

Edit: I was only asking for a clarification on what my professor was requiring of me, I now understand what this requirement is saying and I believe that this has been thoroughly answered.

I have a project that i have to do for my c++ class and this is a requirement of the project.

> Except for the print menu function, all user defined
>   functions(functions written by the programmer) must be called from
>   main. No user defined functions other than the print menu function can
>   be called from other user defined functions.

Comment: `main() -> foo() -> print()` = ok, `main() -> foo() -> bar()` no good.

Comment: im not asking for anyone to do this for me, I'm just asking for a clarification.

Comment: I just posted an answer and realized that in essence I just repeated what you wrote. It's difficult to give clarification if we don't know what exactly is unclear.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an English comprehension problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a strange requirement. During your homework you might write some functions. Or you might not, and your `main()` will be one unreadable big pile of lines that only you can read and understand, on a good day.

But, you can decide to pretify your code by moving some code from `main()` to some newly introduced functions. One function to read all data from input, one function to do something with that data, one function to write result to output. Such kind of things.

The requirement demands that all functions must be called only in `main()`. You must not call any function from any other function except `main()`.

I guess this requirement makes it easy for the teacher to read your code.

Comment: Except that the "print menu function" can be called from anywhere.

Comment: so i can put the "PrintMenu function" in another function, but no other functions I write can be added to the other functions. but that to me just seems silly to even do because it would only print a menu during that function that i defined.

Comment: @kuthedk: Correct, correct and correct. Well the last one is almost correct. Your use of the term "during" suggests you don't quite grok how console output works yet. The output (your "menu") will still be there on the screen after the function ends so you do not need to worry about that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit so in general I would do something like this `void OtherFunction(){ code code code PrintMenu();}`

Comment: @kuthedk: Sure why not

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i accidentally hit enter and just edited my last question sorry for any confusion

Answer (score -2):

That means you cannot nest functions, like this function definition

```
void A(){
  int B();
}
```

then you are only able to call your functions from `main()`

Comment: int B(); in this example is another function that has also been defined?

Comment: No, the requirement is about *calls* from one function to another, not declaring a function inside a function definition.

Comment: Right, does that mean that we cannot either define nested functions so that we cannot explicitly call functions from inside other functions?